# adding objects from a windows form into a c# list

Tags: c#, list, winforms

I have a lot of windows form components that i need to add to an array. Currently  i just have a large amount of adds to a list and this is definitely bad practice.

```
        panelList.Add(panel1);
        panelList.Add(panel2);
        panelList.Add(panel3);
        panelList.Add(panel4);
        panelList.Add(panel5);
        panelList.Add(panel6);
        panelList.Add(panel7);
        panelList.Add(panel8);
        panelList.Add(panel9);
        panelList.Add(panel10);
        panelList.Add(panel11);
        panelList.Add(panel12);
        panelList.Add(panel13);
        panelList.Add(panel14);
        panelList.Add(panel15);
        panelList.Add(panel16);
        panelList.Add(panel17);
        panelList.Add(panel18);
        panelList.Add(panel19);
        panelList.Add(panel20);
        panelList.Add(panel21);
        panelList.Add(panel22);
        panelList.Add(panel23);
        panelList.Add(panel24);
        panelList.Add(panel25);

        labelList.Add(label1);
        labelList.Add(label2);
        labelList.Add(label3);
        labelList.Add(label4);
        labelList.Add(label5);      
        labelList.Add(label6);
        
        labelList.Add(label7);
        labelList.Add(label8);
        labelList.Add(label9);
        labelList.Add(label10);
        labelList.Add(label11);
        labelList.Add(label12);
        labelList.Add(label13);
        labelList.Add(label14);
        labelList.Add(label15);
        labelList.Add(label16);
        labelList.Add(label17);
        labelList.Add(label18);
        labelList.Add(label19);
        labelList.Add(label20);
        labelList.Add(label21);
        labelList.Add(label22);
        labelList.Add(label23);
        labelList.Add(label24);
        labelList.Add(label26);
```

is there a way in c# to add these elements in a for loop etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all of the labels, panels, etc. in their own encapsulating panel. This will make them children of the panel, and you can iterate over them easily:

```cs
foreach (Control ctrl in panelContainer.Controls) // panelContainer is a Panel
{
    labelList.Add((Label) ctrl);
}
```

**I strongly recommend not to do that.** It's kind of messy in the designer (if you're using that), adds more uncecessary controls to worry about, and if you accidentally add something that isn't a label, your app will crash.

A simpler way to do it is by using the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872444/13580938) on a similar question. You can apply it as such:

```cs
panelList.AddRange(this.FindChildControlsOfType<Panel>());
labelList.AddRange(this.FindChildControlsOfType<Label>());
```

If you insist on iterating, that's obviously doable as well:

```
foreach (Label label in this.FindChildControlsOfType<Label>())
{
    labelList.Add(label);
}
```

Comment: ok thank you, just wondering with the .AddRange function does it add them in order of label1, label2, label3, label4 etc. or just randomly. I need the labels and panels in that specific order. Thanks.

Comment: It's going to add them in the same way that the code below `AddRange` (the foreach loop) will, i.e., the way they're ordered in WinForms internally. If you need them in a specific order, you can write a sorter to sort the list after you've added your items. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796835/13580938